# Find maximum weighted sum over all m-subsequences

Tags: c, algorithm, sum, weighted, kadanes-algorithm

I was trying to solve the following problem:

[Weighted Sum Problem](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/public/WEIGHTED-SUM.pdf)

The closest problem I have done before is Kadane's algorithm, so I tried the "max ending here" approach, which led to the following DP-based program. The idea is to break the problem down into smaller identical problems (the usual DP).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


main(){
int i, n, m, C[20002], max, y, x, best, l, j;
int a[20002], b[20002];
scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&C[i]);
}
a[0] = C[0];
max = C[0];
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    max = (C[i]>max) ? C[i] : max;
    a[i] = max;
}

for(l=0;l<n;l++){
    b[l] = 0;
}

for(y=2;y<m+1;y++){

    for(x=y-1;x<n;x++){

        best = max = 0;
        for(j=0;j<y;j++){
        max += (j+1) * C[j];
        }

        for(i=y-1;i<x+1;i++){
            best = a[i-1] + y * C[i];
            max = (best>max) ? best : max;
        }
        b[x] = max;
    }

    for(l=0;l<n;l++){
    a[l] = b[l];                 
    }
}
printf("%d\n",b[n-1]);
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

But this program does not work within the specified time limit (space limit is fine). Please give me a hint on the algorithm to be used on this problem.

EDIT.

Here is the explanation of the code:
Like in Kadane's, my idea is to look at a particular C[i], then take the maximum weighted sum for an m-subsequence ending at C[i], and finally take the max of all such values over all i. This will give us our answer. Now note that when you look at an m-subsequence ending at C[i], and take the maximum weighted sum, this is equivalent to taking the maximum weighted sum of an (m-1)-subsequence, contained in C[0] to C[i-1]. And this is a smaller problem which is identical to our original one. So we use recursion. To avoid double calling to functions, we make a table of values f[i][j], where f[i-i][j] is the answer to the problem which is identical to our problem with n replaced by i and m replaced by j. That is, we build a table of f[i][j], and our final answer is f[n-1][m] (that is, we use memoization). Now noting that only the previous column is required to compute an entry f[i][j], it is enough to keep only arrays. Those arrays are 'a' and 'b'.

Sorry for the long length, can't help it. :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) I am looking at the example implementation given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem Looks like Kadane's algorithm is linear O(n) and your code is cubic O(n^3). Could you please comment your code so that one can understand better the operations that you are doing? Also, what is the meaning of your variables, like `a` and `b`?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij Thank you for your interest. I have added the explanation in the original post.
Yes, my algorithm is O(n^3), which is why I think this is not the right line of thought.

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is correct. But there is a problem with your algorithm.

You could replace the body of the inner loop

```
    best = max = 0;
    for(j=0;j<y;j++){
    max += (j+1) * C[j];
    }

    for(i=y-1;i<x+1;i++){
        best = a[i-1] + y * C[i];
        max = (best>max) ? best : max;
    }
    b[x] = max;
```

with

```
   b[x] = MAX(b[x-1],a[x-1] + y * C[x]);
```

This will improve the time complexity of the algorithm. I.e. avoid recomputing `b[i]` for 
all `i < x`. A common trait in dynamic programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that code was unnecessary. :)
(a[x] should be a[x-1]. I tried to edit it, but the edit is too small, so it wouldn't let me.)

Comment: Yes, indeed, a[x-1] it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try `0/1 Knapsack without repetition` approach where at each step we decide whether to include an item or not.

Let `MWS(i, j)` represent the `optimal maximum weighted sum` of the sub-problem `C[i...N]` where `i` varies from `0 <= i <= N` and `1 <= j <= M`, and our goal is to find out the value of `MWS(0, 1)`.

MWS(i, j) can be represented in the recursive ways as follow.

[image]

I am leaving the boundary conditions handling as an exercise for you.

Comment: I will try to code this approach tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what was suggested by Dmitri Chubarov.

Comment: then its good for you .... now you know both the correct approach and the working code :)